# Haskell gnuplot not working displaying plot

Tags: haskell, gnuplot, ghc

I've been using the Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC) to learn Haskell. I installed the gnuplot package using Cabal (I used the command `cabal install --lib gnuplot`). I can load the gnuplot module, however, when I try to use gnuplot, it doesn't display the function plot:

```
ghci> :m Graphics.Gnuplot.Simple     
ghci> plotFunc [][1.0,1.01..10.0] sin
ghci> ghc-9.2.8.exe: gnuplot: readCreateProcessWithExitCode: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package, which doesn't solve the problem. I think it might be linked to my computers Path and environment variables, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Is gnuplot itself installed? It looks like the library is installed OK, but at runtime it can not find the gnuplot executable.

Comment: Run `where gnuplot` in a cmd prompt. Does it print the file path?

Comment: You need to install `gnuplot` itself. The library basically generates a gnuplot script and passes this to the `gnuplot` executable to plot it.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell's gnuplot library does *not* replicate the `gnuplot` program. It basically is a wrapper that writes a gnuplot program and passes that to gnuplot.

But in order to plot, gnuplot thus has to do the actual work. You thus need to install gnuplot on your system. For example for a debian-like system, we an install `gnuplot` with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnuplot
```